# How do I change the damage from an item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a datapack and I want to change the damage from the scythe, but I can't figure out how to implement it, I want to change from 17 damage to 8.

```
/give @s carrot_on_a_stick{display:{Name:'{"text":"Netherite Scythe","color":"reset","italic":false}', Lore:['{"text":"A Scythe forged with","color":"gray","italic":false}','{"text":"the great power of Demons.","color":"gray","italic":false}','{"text":"right click to dash","color":"dark_gray","italic":true}']},HideFlags:5,RepairCost:0,Unbreakable:1b,CustomModelData:123456,Netherite_Scythe:1b,Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:mending",lvl:1s}],AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.movement_speed",Name:"generic.movement_speed",Amount:0.35,Operation:1,UUID:[I;1023075511,1062879676,-1183574452,1894509967],Slot:"mainhand"},{AttributeName:"generic.attack_damage",Name:"generic.attack_damage",Amount:17,Operation:0,UUID:[I;933272347,1504660042,-1451755340,-1807695170],Slot:"mainhand"}]} 1
```

I'm writing on version 1.19, please help

Answer (score 1):

If you mean attack damage I would suggest changing the Name:"generic.attack_damage",Amount:17 to an 8